# Reverse a string except for the characters contained within { } with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to reverse a string except the characters inside of "{}". I know how to reverse a string but I'm not sure how to create the exception. Please help.

```js
 function reverseChar(string2){
    let string2Array = string2.split('');
    let newArray = [];
  
    for(let x = string2Array.length-1; x >= 0; x--){
      newArray.push(string2Array[x])
    }
    console.log(newArray)

}
reverseChar("ab{cd}efg")
reverseChar("ab{cd}ef{gh}i")
```

Comment: Can you tell what are the expected output for the two cases you have there?

Comment: Is the output for reverseChar("ab{cd}ef{gh}i")  supposed to be :  "i{gh}fe{cd}ba"?

Comment: Or should it be "ba{cd}fe{gh}i"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, maybe, this is what you want?

```js
function reverse(str) {
  return str.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/}\w+\{/g,a=>reverse(a))
}

console.log(reverse("ab{cd}efg"))
console.log(reverse("ab{cd}ef{gh}i"))
```

The RegExp `/}\w+\{/g` will find any string of characters and numbers (`\w+`) that is enclosed by `}` and `{`. These patterns will exist after the whole string is `reverse()`-d initially. In the callback function to the `String.replace()` method the matched string will then be reversed again.

Comment: what's "/}\w+\{/g"?

Comment: See edited post above ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this logic:

- Get all the parts
- If the part does not have special character, reverse it and set it.
- Reverse the parts array
- Join all the parts back and return it

```js
function reverseChar(string2) {
  const regex = /(\w+(?=\{|$)|\{\w+\})/g
  return string2.match(regex)
    .map((str) => /\{/.test(str) ? str : str.split("").reverse().join(""))
    .reverse()
    .join("")
}
console.log(reverseChar("ab{cd}efg"))
console.log(reverseChar("ab{cd}ef{gh}i"))
```